# Graying out an image in D3js

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I'm using images as nodes in a D3js force directed graph. On a particular event, I want to gray-out this image.
Is there a way to to achieve this?

I tried reducing opacity but it doesn't give the desired effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you actually want to make it grayscale?

Borrowing from [here](http://webdev.brillout.com/2010/10/desaturate-image-without-javascript.html).

```
// set up filter
svg.append('filter')
  .attr('id','desaturate')
  .append('feColorMatrix')
  .attr('type','matrix')
  .attr('values',"0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0");

// then on the nodes to gray apply it
node.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", "https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico")
  .style("filter", function(d, i) {
      if (i % 2 == 0) {
        return ("filter", "url(#desaturate)");
      } else {
        return "";
      }
    });
```

Example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PU9MN6AyCM1sEv19GKAh?p=preview).

Comment: Can you please explain the solution in short? I don't understand the attributes of the filter

Comment: @Natasha, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix)