# D3.JS: Discrete filter for image processing

Tags: image, d3.js, svg, filter, discretization

I have an arbitrary raster pattern where blue is -1.0, white is 0.0 and orange is 1.0 (left image). Need to develop an SVG filter, similar to this reference [Graying out an image in D3js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27357917/graying-out-an-image-in-d3js)), but for discretizing (right image).

[image]

Eventually, values for all three colors are known.

Pretty sure that basically, I need to go through each pixel and calculate the distance to blue and orange and set the closest.

But, I don't know what filter method I should use out of these https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter (under See Also).

And, maybe, there is another solution, which isn't based on distance calculations?

Comment: What format is your input raster? And do you need SVG for any other reason than the filter?

Comment: The input format is PNG. Yes, I could use canvas to discretize image, actually, it's the current solution, but I'm looking for an elegant way with SVG filter, while this PNG image is a part of svg:pattern.

Comment: This code makes duotone : __svg.append("filter").append("feComponentTransfer").attr("color-interpolation-filters", "linearRGB").append("feFuncR").attr("type", "table").attr("tableValues", "0.486 0.937").append("feFuncG").attr("type", "table").attr("tableValues", "0.812 0.360").append("feFuncB").attr("type", "table").attr("tableValues", "0.847 0.125")__

Maybe I need to tweak somehow a grayscale matrix just before doing this to 'increase' contrast.

Comment: Have found this tutorial: https://www.thirdandgrove.com/using-svg-filters-apply-accessible-high-contrast-filter-content 
Worth of tryings

Answer (score 1):

If I do a black and white pattern with the middle color #808080

[image]

And apply the following filter:

```
<filter id="threshold" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
<feComponentTransfer>
<feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
<feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
<feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0 1"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
<feComponentTransfer>
<feFuncR type="table" tableValues="0.486 0.937"/>
<feFuncG type="table" tableValues="0.812 0.360"/>
<feFuncB type="table" tableValues="0.847 0.125"/>
</feComponentTransfer>
</filter>
```

I've got what I want at the end

[image]

So, it's a half-way solution.